# cannot clicked on a collapsed button using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I cannot click on `CHANGE PASSWORD` which is a [collapsed button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHEW9.png) found under `HOME`

HTML Code when the buttons [are collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE9Ae.png):

```
<div class="collapsed" style="">
        <span>HOME</span>
        <a href="../../main.asp">Home</a>
        <a href="../../chg_pass.asp">CHANGE PASSWORD</a>
         <a href="ADD/reset_pass.asp">RESET PASSWORD</a>       
      </div>
```

when the buttons [aren't collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRhr2.png):

```
<div class="" style="">
        <span>HOME</span>
        <a href="../../main.asp">Home</a>
        <a href="../../chg_pass.asp">CHANGE PASSWORD</a>
                 <a href="ADD/reset_pass.asp">RESET PASSWORD</a>           
      </div>
```

I've already tried:
`driver.find_element_by_link_text("CHANGE PASSWORD").click()` and `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/a[2]').click()`
but  im getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[1]/a[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.82)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00817AC3+2587331]
        Ordinal0 [0x007AADD1+2141649]
        Ordinal0 [0x006A3BB8+1063864]
        Ordinal0 [0x006D01CE+1245646]
        Ordinal0 [0x006D03CB+1246155]
        Ordinal0 [0x006FA612+1418770]
        Ordinal0 [0x006E86D4+1345236]
        Ordinal0 [0x006F8A0A+1411594]
        Ordinal0 [0x006E84A6+1344678]
        Ordinal0 [0x006C53F6+1201142]
        Ordinal0 [0x006C62E6+1204966]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009BDF22+1680738]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A70DBC+2413564]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008AD151+563089]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008ABF13+558419]
        Ordinal0 [0x007B081E+2164766]
        Ordinal0 [0x007B5508+2184456]
        Ordinal0 [0x007B5650+2184784]
        Ordinal0 [0x007BF5BC+2225596]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75AA6739+25]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77D68E7F+1215]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77D68E4D+1165]


C:\Users\mjajd\Desktop>[1468:16276:0212/230339.532:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[1468:16276:0212/230339.533:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[1468:17348:0212/230339.536:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [23:03:39.536] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[1468:16276:0212/230339.536:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[1468:17348:0212/230339.540:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [23:03:39.540] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Comment: Is the menu within `HOME` with text _Home_, _CHANGE PASSWORD_ and _RESET PASSWORD_ collapsed(open) by default?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium by default it looks like [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/926140612829392936/942262719975931974/unknown.png)